# deploy java application with gitlab ci

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a very simple gitlab ci setup that builds a java application with maven.  At the last step I simply want to kick off the application run with a `java -jar app.jar &` cmd.

The problem is on gitlab build page the process doesn't exit and will keep waiting there until timeout. Am I using it in a wrong way? Or any suggestions on a better implementation? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Any result yet ? I'm interested too :)